# How many linear independent vectors do I need for a subspace?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Rather an elementary question but I couldn't find one definite answer, but while working through my script I got the following intention :

For a Subspace of $R^2$ I do need two linear independent vectors. 
Even if both of the vectors have more than two dimensions, like  $\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $

is that correct ?

What makes me wonder here, is that any linear combination of these two is never possible to draw in a just two dimensional system, but it was a correct answer to one of our exercises.

Edit: So I have got a formal definition from a very common textbook for advanced mathematics:

" The dimension of a vector space, is the number of elements in the set of a basis" , while a basis was defined as " a set of linear independent elements".

So I think I am mixing up two different terms here: Dimension and space of R^2:

The dimensions of the two vectors above is 2, while the subspace they are in is R^3 - is it like that?

Comment: As stated, the question makes no sense, since the two vectors that you mentioned do not belong to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: You don't need any vectors at all. The set consisting of the zero vector is a subspace.

Comment: Do you mean a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$? That’s not at all the same thing as $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: As stated above and in the only answer, I had a misunderstanding in the topic itself. Thanks so far since it helped me out.

Comment: Think amd figured it out - I had a wrong idea of "two dimensional" and R^2

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be some (linear) space of dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Then the definition of $Y$ being a subspace of $X$ always contains the condition
$$ Y \subseteq X.$$
This is why your example does not work. A basis of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has to be a set of elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as well.
Returning to your question we have the following:

If $Y$ is a $m$-dimensional subspace of $X$ then any basis of $Y$ consists of (exactly) $m$ linearly independant vectors (with $m \leq n$).

Comment: The dimensions of the two vectors above is 2, while the subspace they are in is R^3 - is it like that?

Comment: Well, the 2 vectors above are linearly independent elements of the 3-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^3$ and hence, their span is a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. This subspace is not $\mathbb{R}^3$ itself (because a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ consists of 3 linearly independent vectors).

Also a vector itself doesn't really have a dimension as the dimension is always corresponding to some vector space (in your case $\mathbb{R}^3$). So the dimension belongs either to the space or subspace you are talking about.